# Let $x=\sin^2 \theta$ and if $\sin \theta \sin 2\theta \sin 3\theta \sin 4\theta=ax^2+bx^3+cx^4+dx^ 5$, find $\frac{10a-7b+15c-5d}{862}$

Tags: trigonometry

I am just looking for some insight into the question, ie. I do not know how to start it. Directly simplifying the given expression gives terms like $\sin \theta $ and $\sin ^3\theta$, which would be $x^{\frac12}$ and $x^{\frac 32}$. I couldn’t think of any other way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin t\sin2t\sin3t\sin4t$$

$$=\sin t\sin2t(3\sin t-4\sin^3t)2\sin2t\cos2t$$

$$=\sin^2t(3-4\sin^2t)\cdot2(\sin2t)^2\cos2t$$

Now $\cos2t=?-?\sin^2t$

and $\sin^22t=1-\cos^22t=?$

Comment: The answer is supposed to be an integer

Comment: @Aditya, Where  have you found non-integers?

Comment: I changed the question a bit, please have a look